# Clarification on what exactly is cached by EF Plus

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus, entity-framework-extensions

If I have a table of service requests and I run the following code on it:

```
var serviceRequest = await _ctx.ServiceRequests.DeferredAny(t => t.Id == h.Id).FromCacheAsync("ServiceRequestByID");
```

Would that be the same as saying save this query:

SELECT * FROM ServiceRequests WHERE ID = 12345

or is it the same as saying:

SELECT * FROM ServicesRequests  (Then from that newly cached data find id 12345).

In other words, what exactly is cached in regards to using the line of code above? And if I come back later with a new ID, then will it query the cache or go to the database because it saved only the first ID's record the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is cached.

In your case, the boolean value result is cached and not the entity.

If you query with a different ID, it will query the database and cache the result as well with the other result

Comment: Additional question related... If I have a small module in my application that may query multiple related tables, would it be smarter to just get them all a tag of "{moduleName}" and then when a record is updates, just expire all the queries with that tag? Or is there a better way?

Comment: You can specify more than one tag, so the answer highly depends on how you use it. For example, if you have an importation that does both country & state, then having a tag for both caches can make it easier to expire them. The answer will vary depending on how you want to use the cache, I don't want any general recommendation on this subject.